# How to render rich text in React?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, rtf, richtext

**Rich text stored in MySQL Database:**

```
<p>Something something</p><p>Something something</p>
```

I fetch the Database content and store inside description state .

**React code :**

`<div >{ description }</div>`

The output is :

```
<p>Something something</p><p>Something something</p>
```

There shoult NOT be `<p>` tagse there and the sentences should be in 2 lines.

---

Comment: what you're looking for is [react's dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#common-props).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a raw HTML string to an element like so:

```
const description = { __html: '<p>Something something</p><p>Something something</p>' };
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={description} />;
```

I hope this will be help you as well.